# How to call function from function array (React js)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I Created array that contains functions and now I am trying to call a function from that array, I tried this code but it's not working and I have no idea how can I do it becuase I am pretty new at react js. Can someone help me with this?

here is my code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../App.css";

export default class Chart extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      stockChartXValues: "",
      stockChartYValues: "",
      type: props.data,
    };
  }

  getBTC = () => {
    // .....
  };

  getETH = () => {
    // .....
  };

  getADA = () => {
    // .....
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    // here I am trying to run a function according to the "type" variable
    var options = ["BTC", "ETH", "ADA"];
    var functions = [this.getBTC, this.getETH, this.getADA];
    var func = functions.indexOf(options.indexOf(this.state.type));
    func.call();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello world</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: have you tried `func()`?

Comment: yes, it's not working as well

Comment: instead of this approach, you can pass `type` prop to a function and execute target function in a switch case statement. That would be a bit more readable and less magic strings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to get function with the index you found;

```
  var func = functions.indexOf(options.indexOf(this.state.type));// this returns index not the actual func
  functions[func] && functions[func]()
```

My Approach would be like;

```
  getBTC = () => {
    // .....
  };

  getETH = () => {
    // .....
  };

  getADA = () => {
    // .....
  };

  getCoin = (type) => {
    switch(type) {
    case "BTC": this.getBTC()
      return
    case "ADA":...
    ...
    ...
    }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getCoin(this.state.type)
  }
```

Comment: oh yea you right but its still not calling the function

Comment: I am getting this error ```Uncaught TypeError: functions[func] is not a function```

Comment: func should contain a valid index. Could you check you get a valid index e.g 0,1 or 2